# Deepsea obfuscator ignores settings with Windows Phone 8 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, obfuscation

I have tried to obfuscate a WindowsPhone8 dll with help of Deepsea Obfuscator version 4.4.1.79.

**AssemblyInfo.cs** contains:

```
[assembly: Obfuscation( Feature = "add-prefix /prefix:abc") ]
[assembly: Obfuscation( Feature = "inject /a:xxx.Phone.dll /internal:true" )]
```

This configuration works fine with .NET 4.0 Framework, the final dll does not have readable class names and methods, generates obfuscated control flow. But for WindowsPhone8 dll I've got the reversed result. How can  I get the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can forcibly write which char set you'd like to use:

> [assembly: Obfuscation( Feature = "rename /charset:unreadable")]

or you can use ASCII mixed symbols